# upload speed control from IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

If I am using IIS 7.0 + Server 2008/Vista Enterprise, any ways from IIS 7.0 side to control the upload speed? For example, max upload speed at 1M bytes/second?

Any configuration based easy solution is great! And any programming based solution is also appreciated. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

There is bandwidth throtelling available in IIS 7.0, but that is only available per website, I am not sure if its available on per request basis.

You can find it under Microsoft Web Platform installer, there are couple of configuration tools available to install.

Comment: I think it could only control download speed? Not upload?

Comment: I agree, Bit Rate Throttling seems only limit download, not upload speed.